# What could you combine .uniq with to keep the original order of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, uniq

How would you either shift the order of an array or keep the natural order of an array when using the Ruby .uniq method or even .to_set?

So for example:

```
([3,4,4,3,6,3]) # =>  [4,6,3])

### with current method my solution outputs:
 
Expected: [4, 6, 3], instead got: [3, 4, 6]
```

These are all the other approaches I've tried so far:

```
def solve arr 

#arr.each do |charas| arr << charas unless arr.include?(charas)
#end 
  arr.to_set.to_a
  # arr.uniq
  # arr & arr
  # arr.to_set
  
end
```

Example tests:

```
(solve([3,4,4,3,6,3]),[4,6,3])
    Test.assert_equals(solve([1,2,1,2,1,2,3]),[1,2,3])
    Test.assert_equals(solve([1,2,3,4]),[1,2,3,4])
    Test.assert_equals(solve([1,1,4,5,1,2,1]),[4,5,2,1])
```

Comment: Why do you expect `4` to come before `3`?

Comment: because it was the original order of the array and a requirement to pass the tests.

Comment: I see both a `3` before a `4` and a `4` before a `3` in the "original order of the array", so the result you have is perfectly fine.

Comment: I doubt that many readers understand your question. It took me quite a while to figure it out and I still may be wrong. Please tell me if the explanation I gave in my answer is correct. Regardless, you need to edit your question to clarify. I also suggest you remove the refence to `.to_set` which only muddles things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`reverse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse) twice: before and after [`uniq`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq). This: `reverse.uniq` returns the unique elements in the order from *last to first occurrence in the **original** array*. The second `reverse` puts these elements in the order found in the input array:

```
my_array.reverse.uniq.reverse
```

For example:

```
puts [3,4,4,3,6,3].reverse.uniq.reverse.inspect     # => [4, 6, 3]
puts [1,2,1,2,1,2,3].reverse.uniq.reverse.inspect   # => [1, 2, 3]
puts [1,2,3,4].reverse.uniq.reverse.inspect         # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts [1,1,4,5,1,2,1].reverse.uniq.reverse.inspect   # => [4, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Nice one! Moreover, I could not have figured out the question without your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want the unique elements ordered by their last index in the `Array`.

We can handle this by using `uniq`, `sort_by`, and `rindex` (which will return the last index for a given element)

```
arr = [3,4,4,3,6,3]
arr.uniq.sort_by(&arr.method(:rindex))
#=> [4,6,3]
```

Comment: A little long-winded, but I like!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is that if `arr` is a given array we are to produce an array `brr` containing the unique elements of `arr` that has the following property: for any two indices `i` and `j`, `0 <= i < j <= brr.size-1`, `arr.rindex(brr[i]) < arr.rindex(brr[j]`. This reads, "The last instance of `brr[i]` in `arr` precedes the last instance of `brr[j]` in `arr`.

Here is a way of producing the desired array in *one pass*.

```
require 'set'
```

```
def weird_uniq(arr)
  set = Set.new
  h = arr.reverse_each.with_object([]) { |n,a| a.unshift(n) if set.add?(n) }
end
```

```
weird_uniq [3,4,4,3,6,3]
  #=> [4,6,3])
weird_uniq [1,2,1,2,1,2,3]
  #=> [1,2,3]
weird_uniq [1,2,3,4]
  #=> [1,2,3,4]
weird_uniq [1,1,4,5,1,2,1]
  #=> [4, 5, 2, 1]
```

See [Set#add?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F). Set lookups, like hash key lookups, are very fast, nearly independent of the size of the set.

Comment: Reverse iteration and unshift is a creative single pass solution. Although since we are using set for look up why not leverage it completely `arr.inject(Set.new) {|m,e| set.delete(e).add(e)}.to_a`? Any downsides?

Comment: How I love ruby. So many options for the proverbial cat `s.uniq.sort_by(&s.method(:rindex))`

Comment: @engineersmnky, I especially like #2. Please revise and undelete your answer. Let me think about order-preserving re `.to_a`. (I thought you did live Ruby.)

Comment: #1 looks good too. (That should be `m.delete(e).add(e)`.) The fact that the set's underlying hash preserves key-insertion order should ensure the set does the same. ****x2!

Comment: Yeah typo on my part. It is unsurprising difficult to write code and markdowns on a cellphone but maybe I'll benchmark when I get back to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

What order are you expecting? do you want the number arranged by their last index?

```
def solve arr 

#arr.each do |charas| arr << charas unless arr.include?(charas)
#end 
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |element,arr|
    if arr.include?(element)
      arr.delete(element)
      arr<<element
    else
      arr<<element
    end
  end
end
p solve([3,4,4,3,6,3]) # =>  [4,6,3])
```

Comment: Yes sorry should have clarified. Numbers in array should take on their last position. I've update the question with example tests below — thank you¬!

Comment: `arr.inject([]) {|a,e| a.<<(a.delete(e) || e)}` is a little cleaner or even `arr.inject([]) {|a,e| a.<<(a.delete(e) {e})}`

Comment: You're right! I've never seen the ```{e}``` expression before, i've got a lot to learn haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you expect to get the order you're showing. There's likely code you haven't included in your question. Regardless, on Ruby 2.7.1 [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) certainly appears to preserve the original order:

```
[3,4,4,3,6,3].uniq
#=> [3, 4, 6]
```

If you want to do something different, a logical approach might be to iterate over the array using [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), using the index to manage the order of elements in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer. It's a bit odd though I initially used ```arr.uniq``` and it sorted the array.

Comment: @KobbyAdarkwa It doesn't sort the array, it keeps the order of the first encounters. If you want the last encounters you'll have to double reverse. `[3,4,4,3,6,3].reverse.uniq.reverse #=> [4,6,3]`